# Conditional Formatting to be set as a cell variable?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm going to try to make as much sense out of this as I can, I've been working on VBA for an entirety of 3 days now and this is a part of one of my projects for my internship.

In short, I have a set of numbers, and if this number is out of the 12-70 range, it is a bad data point and should not be included in other linked calculations. However, the number needs to remain there, and I cannot change other linked formulas directly.

So, my idea is to change the cell to an "N/A", but return the display of that cell to the original number (if that is possible). Here's my code (which is functional):

```
'This will take all questionable data and remove it from calculation
Dim i As Variant
Dim j As Variant

For Each j In Array(6, 7, 10)
    For i = 3 To 500
        If Cells(i,j) = "N/A" Or Cells(i,j) = "" Then

        ElseIf Cells(i,j) < 12 Or Cells(i,j) > 70 Then
            Cells(i, 11) = Cells(i,j)
            Cells(i,j).NumberFormat = "0;0;0;[Red]""Bad Data"""
            Cells(i,j) = "N/A"
        End If
    Next i
Next j
```

So, as of now, this rewrites the original number into column 11 next to where it originally was, changes the value to N/A, and then displays as "Bad Data".

Is there a way to change that "Bad Data" display to display the original number, WHILE maintaining N/A as the actual cell value?

Comment: Have you tried a number formatting rule, something like this `[<12]"N/A";[>70]"N/A";General` (i had to play with this a bit to make sure it at least somewhat worked and it seems too..)

Comment: The problem is I want "N/A" to be the actual cell value and the number to be just the display, not the other way around. I'm honestly not even sure if this is possible, but I'm not all that savvy in VBA yet, either.

Comment: The way I would do it would be to put the number into a comment on the cell. This way it could be seen when you hover your mouse over it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here it is! See comments for explanation. Hope that helps!

```
Sub set_Cell_Variable()
    'This will take all questionable data and remove it from calculation
    Dim i As Variant
    Dim j As Variant

    ' Two new variables 
    Dim strTemp As String
    Const QUOTE = """" 

    For Each j In Array(6, 7, 10)
        For i = 3 To 500
            If Cells(i, j) = "N/A" Or Cells(i, j) = "" Then

            ElseIf Cells(i, j) < 12 Or Cells(i, j) > 70 Then
                Cells(i, 11) = Cells(i, j)
                ' Store the cell value as String. 
                ' That way it can go into NumberFormat
                strTemp = CStr(Cells(i, j).Value)
                ' Add it to NumberFormat dynamically
                Cells(i, j).NumberFormat = "0;0;0;[Red]" & QUOTE & strTemp & QUOTE
                Cells(i, j) = "N/A"
            End If
        Next i
    Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @loannis! Clever end addition I couldn't pick on, works like a charm. Thanks @martin too, your idea worked nicely as well.